# How to get multiple PHP files output into a single a file for further usage of those output?

Tags: php, include, require

I am trying to get the output of multiple PHP files into a single PHP file where I can save them into different variables for further usage.

For a single PHP file, I used `include` and it works well. But for multiple files I don't know what to do.

Do you have any experiences or advices on how to achieve this ?

I had three php files called a.php,b.php and c.php. Now in each file i am echoing an array as output. For first php file i done like below to save the output of that in fourth php file called d.php

```
ob_start();
include_once('a.php');
$output= ob_get_clean();

echo "<pre>";print_r($output);
```

Now what to do for getting second and third php files outputs.

Comment: You can `include` multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
<?php
$string1 = get_include_contents('somefile1.php');
$string2 = get_include_contents('somefile2.php');

function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}

?>
```